# Can we use OpenVPN as a site-to-site bridged vpn

Tags: vpn

We have two sites, whoch we need to be in a same L2 network. Can we use Openvpn to make them look like one L2 network (for devices connected atleast)? What would be the most proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can,

Set up a box on each network, and configure L2 OpenVPN (dev tap) (one host must be the server, the other a client) - just follow one of many L2 OpenVPN tutorials.

After you get it working, you get a tap interface on each host in each network, which you can bridge to your existing network interface.

While this setup works, be careful not to have 2 DHCP servers running at the same time (one on each side of the network), or at least give them different IP ranges. Also, all broadcasts (DHCP, ARP, etc.) will be sent over the tunnel to/from both sides, which might pose a problem if the network is large enough, and the coonnection between them too slow.

Comment: So if i make br0 bridge, and add eth0 and tap0 on both sides, it should work? All IPs are static

Comment: Yes, it should. Also, watch out if you have the same IP used on both networks - that will not work.

Comment: Yes, just needed confirmation if it supports connecting two distant network into one virtual.